# Evaluating a limit of $f(x)$ given $\lim f(x)/x^2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Given that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^2}=6$$

evaluate the following limits:
a) $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$
b) $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$

I'm not quite sure where to even start here if someone could help me out I would appreciate it.

Comment: Just think $g(x)=f(x)/x^2$ as a function that approaches 6 when x approaches 0. Then what's the limit of $x^2g(x)$ and $xg(x)$ when x approaches 0?

Answer (score 7):

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim \limits_{x \to 0} f(x) &= {} \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \bigg( \frac{f(x)}{x^2} \times x^2 \bigg) \\[2mm]
 &= \bigg( \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} \bigg) \times \bigg( \lim \limits_{x \to 0} x^2 \bigg) \\[2mm]
 &= 6 \times 0 \\[2mm]
 &= 0. 
\end{align*}
$$

and, as well

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} &= {} \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \bigg( \frac{f(x)}{x^2} \times x \bigg) \\[2mm]
 &= \bigg( \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} \bigg) \times \bigg( \lim \limits_{x \to 0} x \bigg) \\[2mm]
 &= 6 \times 0 \\[2mm]
 &= 0. 
\end{align*}
$$